# Does Chocolatey check whether a program is already the latest version before attempting to upgrade?

Tags: windows, software-update, chocolatey

*Previously titled: "Does Chocolatey know when a program updates itself?"*

Assume that I have installed a program such as Google Chrome or Telegram via [**Chocolatey**](https://chocolatey.org/):

```
choco install googlechrome
choco install telegram
```

Many programs such as these are known to update themselves, often silently and simply by a restart of the program.

Does Chocolatey <strike>know that a program has updated itself</strike> check whether a program is already the latest version before attempting to upgrade?

Or does it have some internal record-keeping that tells it that an out-of-date version is still installed (and thereby running `choco upgrade` will attempt to install the version that is already installed)?

*Note that [this question](https://superuser.com/q/789190/117986) is about a different issue.*

Comment: How would Chocolatey know?  Chocolatey just installs the application?  The responsibility then falls on the application to update itself or to the user to upgrade it themselves.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question for clarity. Please check. **PS:** You can run `choco upgrade -all` to update all packages that are installed. I'm interested to know how Chocolatey behaves when you do for packages that have already updated themselves.

Comment: Chocolatey is built on the NuGet framework.  Having a understanding of how that framework works will likely answer your question.  Chocolatey is only going to install the same version of a package if you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - it does not. Longer answer - syncing with the current version installed is something on our list to do.

Once you install a self-updating application, you may want to pin the version in Chocolatey so that it no longer attempts to upgrade it with choco.

Comment: Is this still true? How do I pin the version in Chocolatey? Once the software upgrades itself, do uninstalls still work? Should I still run `choco upgrade`? I feel liek this answer begs alot of other questions.